# Javascript - Creating a for loop with increments of 30 steps

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I'm trying create a `for-loop` with increments of 30 steps. The purpose of this is that would like to use it for a very simple and primitive pagination without using any plugins.

First I have a unordered HTML list:

```
<ul id="pagination"></ul>
```

And this is the code I use to populate the list, and set the attributes for the elements. Used the `data-skip` and `data-top` for the sake of this question, but in reality they will be added later to an `url` for a REST call to fetch the data.

```
var total = 115;
var intervalo = Math.ceil(total / 30);
var pagination = document.getElementById('pagination');

for (var c = 1; c <= intervalo; c++) {
    var top = c * 30;
    var skip = (c * 30) - 30;
    console.log('&$skip=' + skip + ' &$top=' + top);
    var li = document.createElement('li');
        li.id = c;
        li.setAttribute('data-skip', '&$skip=' + skip);
        li.setAttribute('data-top', '&$top=' + top);

    var a = document.createElement('a');
        a.href = '#';
        a.textContent = c;

        li.appendChild(a);
        pagination.appendChild(li);
 }
```

The above code returns this in the console:

```
&$skip=0 &$top=30
&$skip=30 &$top=60
&$skip=60 &$top=90
&$skip=90 &$top=120
```

But this is the issue. If you notice `&$skip` always matches the previous `&$top`. In reality what I need is this to return something similar to this:

```
&$skip=0 &$top=30
&$skip=31 &$top=60
&$skip=61 &$top=90
&$skip=91 &$top=120
```

How can I achieve this? I feel like I'm almost there, but I don't get it right. If any other details is needed, please let me know Thanks!

Comment: `for (var c = 1; c <= intervalo; c+=30) {` ???

Comment: I might be over-simplifying this but...
`var skip = (c * 30) - 30+1;`

Comment: I tried that already, but then it would harder (I think) to add the `li` to the list. Thanks!

Comment: @Hodrobond. Good suggestion, the only issue with that is that skip will start on `1`, and it MUST start on `0`.

Comment: If you start at 0 then it should end at 29. isn't it?? 0-29, 30-59, 60-89 etc.

Comment: @faheemfarhan, that would work too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out. It may not be the best option, but it works for me for now. Hopefully will help others, and even someone would provide a better answer than mine. I created an array and I manipulate afterwards.

```
var total = 115;
var intervalo = Math.ceil(total / 30);
var pagination = document.getElementById('pagination');
var range = [];

for (var c = 1; c <= intervalo; c++) {
  var top = c * 30;
  var skip = (c * 30) - 30;
   range.push({  
        skip: skip,
        top: top
   });
  // console.log('&$skip=' + skip + ' &$top=' + top);

 var li = document.createElement('li');
     li.id = c;
     li.setAttribute('data-skip', '&$skip=' + skip);
     li.setAttribute('data-top', '&$top=' + top);

 var a = document.createElement('a');
     a.href = '#';
     a.textContent = c;

  li.appendChild(a);
  pagination.appendChild(li);

  }

 console.log(JSON.stringify(range));

 for (var r = 1; r < range.length; r++) {
     range[r].top = range[r].top - 1;
 }
 console.log(JSON.stringify(range));
```

Answer (score 2):

Just increment by 30 instead of `c++`:

```
for (var c = 1; c <= total; c+=30)
```

Comment: I think you meant for (var c = 1; c <= total; c+=30), Am I right? The loop you provided woul only work adding the `li` to the list.

Comment: I'm sure. If think about it `intervalo` is the result of dividing `var intervalo = Math.ceil(total / 30)`, so in this case it would equal to `4`, and there are `115` elements in total. Thanks anyways, appreciate it.